# Euclidean distance loss function for RNN (keras)

Tags: keras, loss, recurrent-neural-network

I want to set Euclidean distance as a loss function for LSTM or RNN.

What output should such function have: float, (batch_size) or (batch_size, timesteps)?

Model input X_train is (n_samples, timesteps, data_dim). 
Y_train has the same dimensions.

Example code:

```py
def euc_dist_keras(x, y):
    return K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(x - y), axis=-1, keepdims=True))


model = Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(n_units, activation='relu', input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(n_output, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss=euc_dist_keras, optimizer='adagrad')

model.fit(y_train, y_train, batch_size=512, epochs=10)
```

So, should I average loss over timesteps dimension and/or batch_size?

Answer (score 6):

A loss functions will take predicted and true labels and will output a scalar, in Keras:

```
from keras import backend as K 
def euc_dist_keras(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(y_true - y_pred), axis=-1, keepdims=True))
```

Note, that it will not take `X_train` as an input. The loss calculation follows the forward propagation step, and it's value provides the goodness of predicted labels compared to true labels.

> What output should such function have: float, (batch_size) or
>   (batch_size, timesteps)?

The loss function should have scalar output.

> So, should I average loss over timesteps dimension and/or batch_size?

This would not be required to be able to use Euclidean distance as a loss function.

Side note: In your case, I think the problem might be with the neural network architecture, not the loss. Given `(batch_size, timesteps, data_dim)` the output of the `SimpleRNN` will be `(batch_size, timesteps, n_units)`, and the output of `Dense` layer will be `(batch_size, n_output)`. Thus, given your `Y_train` has the shape `(batch_size, timesteps, data_dim)` you would likely need to use `TimeDistributed` [wrapper](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/) applying `Dense` per every temporal slice, and to adjust the number of hidden units in the fully connected layer.