# How to use different loss function in training and test phase

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I want to use a weighted loss function in the training phase and an unweighted loss function in the test phase.

I've tried in_train_phase, but in the test phase, it still uses weighted loss function.

```
def custom_loss():  
        def euclidian_distance_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        edl_in_train = K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square((y_pred - y_true) * weight_matrix().reshape(1, 41, 41, 1))))
        edl = K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(y_pred - y_true)))
        return K.in_train_phase(edl_in_train,edl)

    return euclidian_distance_loss
```

Because the shape of the training data is constant and the test is not so the error came out at the start of the test phase:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes

How can I make this code work or is there any other way to use different loss functions in these 2 phases?

Comment: What's up with that `reshape`? Why do you need it? Any reshape inside custom loss function should be `batch` agnostic, e.g. has `-1` at the first dimension so the shape can be inferred. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46594115/euclidean-distance-loss-function-for-rnn-keras) for possible euclidean distance loss implementation (or many others throughout the web).

Answer (score 0):

At test time, as you're not minimising on the loss function, it doesn't matter exactly what goes in the loss function. What I would do is feed the unweighted loss function as a "metric" - this way it won't impact on training at train time, but at test time you can analyse it yourself to see how your model is dong.